# Proper way to build a Modal component in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a Modal component build in jQuery.
I want to integrate it in an Angular app that does not use jQuery, and I don't just want to have it as an external dependency. By that I mean, I don't what to leave it as a thing that can be called from controllers, but isn't a directive or service.

What I'm confused about is if it would be a good idea to have DOM logic inside an Angular service (`factory`, `service`, `provider`), or if I should just make a directive with `&` expressions? Or maybe both?

Inside controllers, I want to be able to inject `Modal` and call methods to show or hide the modal and set its content.

What would the proper way of doing this be?
I'm not looking for code, but rather guidance of how a "proper Angular" implementation of this would sound.

Thank you.

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/animating-modals-in-angular-js/

Comment: Thanks, although CoffeeScript hurts my eyes. :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about dom logic in an angular service. No, it is not a good idea, and if you really think about it, there is no need for that. What do you need:

- a modal that can close/open
- can execute callbacks based on whether you clicked yes or cancel

For that simple functionality you most certainly don't need any dom logic and especially not any dom logic in your services.

You can use the [$modal](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal) service and do the styling yourself to make it look the same. Take a look at this plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/WLJfs8axxMJ419N2osBY?p=preview

It is as simple as:

```
$modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'someTemplateOfTheModal',
    controller: SomeControllerOfTheModal,
})
```

You can refer to [this](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) for options.

Otherwise, if we are just talking about how to integrate existing jquery stuff in angular, I would still suggest rebuilding it from scratch in the angular way. Basically replace all jquery trigger/event functionality by pure angular.

For example, a modal can be on or off, might have an overlay or not. The modal itself would probably be used to execute a callback event on yes and not on cancel. You might want to also style it using custom classes so you should take that into consideration. Here are the directives you might wanna take a look if you are rebuilding it from scratch:

- ng-if/ng-show (would probably be used to show/hide your modal and/or
  overlay)
- ng-class (would be used to inject any custom classes you might want
  to put on your modal)
- ng-include (in case you want your modal to be templatized)
- ng-click (to do click events on click of your yes/no/cancel buttons
  and/or clicking away from the modal or on the overlay)

You can see that it can get a bit cluttered, so the best thing would be to use angular's $modal service because it has all those features builtin. I think it has everything that you might possibly want from a modal, and you should just style it. But of course, for learning purposes, you might want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Careful with the $modal service, it doesn't play nice with Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough post, baba. I don't want to use angular-ui (which isn't part of Angular) for the $modal implementation, I would rather do it myself and understand how to do that. What isn't clear to me is this: it's obvious that DOM listeners will be in a directive and show/hide methods in a service. However, when I call the show method or a changeModalTitle or a changeModalContent method from the controller, how would the directive know?

Comment: It can have a two-way scope binding ('=') to the title attribute. Then you don't even have to call functions. You can just do: modal.title = 'someTitle'; and your angular would update your model. And besides, @NicolasMoise I use $modal and bootstrap 3 successfully for a long time already. Not sure why you would say that.